# Having issues using statement with discord bot in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, client, bots

I want to make my bot detect messages with *DD in them and avoid deleting them

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
 var bot = new Discord.Client();
  bot.on("message", function(message) {
   var input = message.content.toUpperCase();
    if(input.indexOf("*DD") != -1) {
        if (J===null) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              bot.deleteMessage(message);
           }, 120000);
        }
     }
});
```

Above is an attempt to make messages with *DD in them not be deleted.

```
         bot.on("message", function(message){{
           setTimeout(function() {
             bot.deleteMessage(message)
             }, 120000);
            }
          });
```

Above is a statement that deletes messages after two minutes after they are posted. I was trying to modify the statement so that if it has *DD somewhere in it then it is not deleted.

```
               if (J===null) {
                   ^

               ReferenceError: J is not defined
               at Client.<anonymous> (C:bot.js:115:13)
               at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
               at Client.emit (events.js:188:7)
               at WebSocket.websocket.onmessage(C:InternalClient.js:1924:16)
               at WebSocket.onMessage (C:*WebSocket.js:442:14)
               at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
               at WebSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)
               at Receiver.ontext (C:*WebSocket.js:841:10)
               at C:Receiver.js:536:18
               at Receiver.applyExtensions (C:Receiver.js:371:5)
```

When *DD is typed into Discord chat this error pops up in the console. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What is the variable `J` ?

Comment: I didn't define J, I did't think I had to, I thought J === null was a statement on its own

Answer (score 0):

You are probably unfamiliar with `"use strict";`, when in strict mode all variables must be explicitly declaired. If you are using es6 modules you are probably using strict mode.